# Can I export only part of the interfaces inside .d.ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, interface, export

```
// config.d.ts

export interface Config {
    NAV_STRUCTURE: Node[];
}

interface Node {
    title: string;
}
```

Please see the above example. In this example I want to export only `Config`. However, I find that I can Import `Node` from external .ts as well? Is there any way to restrict the export of `Node`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interfaces are `public` by default I think? Why would you need a private type definition?

Comment: I have a very complex type and I don't want to expose all of the interface, since some of the interfaces are for internal use only.

Answer (score 0):

You might define the `type` or `interface` inside a module file? Not sure if this is recommended practice... but the types won't be available outside that module.

EXAMPLE.TS

```
type Test = string
interface Person {name:string}

export class Example {
    private p:Person           // <- Person type is allowed here
    private t:Test             // <- Test type is allowed here
}
```

APP.TS

```
export class App {
    private p:Person           // <- Person type is NOT allowed here
    private t:Test             // <- Test type is NOT allowed here
}
```